# Decoding the huffman code without too much recursion

Tags: scala, huffman-code

I have just implemented the Huffman code using Scala. However, one of my functions is not working well on big files. It's the decoding function, where I use too much recursion:

```
def decode(tree: BinarySearchTree, bits: List[Boolean]): List[Char] = {
  def searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(t: BinarySearchTree, b: List[Boolean]): List[Char] = t match {
    case LeafNode(ch, _) => if (b.isEmpty) List(ch) else ch :: searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(tree, b)
    case ForkNode(l, r, _, _) => if (b.head == false) searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(l, b.tail) else searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(r, b.tail)
  }
  searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(tree, bits)
}
```

When I have a tiny bits list it's fine, but when my bits list is big (over 10000 items) it'll give a StackOverflow error. I just can't find where I can optimize it using less recursion. I know the problem is with the recursive call in the leaf (as opposed to the fork).

How can I remove this recursive call but still keep the functionality working?

Answer (score 3):

At first sight, your implementation is missing a `.tail` in the `LeafNode` branch, so whenever you hit a `Leaf` node you just keep invoking the same function over and over again, because `bits` is not shrinking.

Secondly, you could make the recursive function tail-recursive, so that it's stack safe:

```
def decode(tree: BinarySearchTree, bits: List[Boolean]): List[Char] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(t: BinarySearchTree, b: List[Boolean], acc: List[Char] = Nil): List[Char] = t match {
    case LeafNode(ch, _) => if (b.isEmpty) acc else searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(tree, b.tail, ch :: acc)
    case ForkNode(l, r, _, _) => if (b.head == false) searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(l, b.tail) else searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(r, b.tail)
  }
  searchCharactersInBinarySearchTree(tree, bits)
}
```

Note that the `tailrec` annotation is not doing anything other than making the compiler check that the method is actually tail-recursive.

Comment: Weirdly, whatever the input this seems to result in an empty Char list...